# Race Condition using onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am trying to call the below 1x1 pixel (sact.atdmt.com) when a link is clicked on. It's actually just returns a 1x1 image but is used to ping our servers and essentially count a click in this instance.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" onclick="javascript:img1=new Image(); img1.src='http://sact.atdmt.com/action/adofat_ImageTest27_1'; img1.height='1'; img1.width='1'" ;="">test</a>
```

The above code only works in IE. I can't figure out why it doesn't work in Chrome or Firefox. I think there is some kind of race condition where the href is being resolved before the onclick function has a change to execute but it's only present in these browsers.

Are there any fixes for this?

Thanks,

Comment: What is that `" ;="` in the end?

Comment: Sorry! That was just a minor error I didnt catch, but it shouldn't cause the race condition I mentioned earlier

Answer (score 1):

Fix the syntax error and add `return false;`

```
<a 
    href="http://www.google.com/" 
    onclick="javascript:img1=new Image(); img1.src='http://sact.atdmt.com/action/adofat_ImageTest27_1'; img1.height='1'; img1.width='1'; return false;"
>test</a>
```

BTW if you're not displaying the image then you don't need to set height/width of the image

Comment: How does adding return false help with the race condition?

Comment: If I add return false the pixel fires off but the button does not click through.... any ideas?

Comment: ah, you wanted to click to actually redirect. Now I get your _race condition_ part. will update answer :)

Comment: Thanks! Please let me know if you find anything :)

Answer (score 0):

Ejay's answer works just fine, but I feel obligated to mention that I usually stay away from onclick=. This is because screen readers won't reliably register onclicks as an actual click event.

So if you are interested... here is the safe way of doing this.

### The JS

```
function imageClickHandler(){
var img1;
var img1=new Image();
img1.src='http://sact.atdmt.com/action/adofat_ImageTest27_1';
img1.height='1';
img1.width='1';
}//end function

document.getElementByID("TheExampleLink").addEventListener("click",imageClickHandler,false);
```

### The HTML

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" id="TheExampleLink">test</a>
```

I hope this helps, and you consider not using onclick. :)

Comment: I like this method, but I am still having a hard time getting the pixel to fire off before being brought to the landing page :(